Object creation in an argument statement in pyhton
I observed the following behavior:
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        print("A.__init__")


class B:
    def __init__(self, a=A()):
        self.a = a
        print("B.__init__")


class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()
        print("C.__init__")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    b1 = B()
    b2 = B()
    b2.a.x = 5
    c1 = C()
    c2 = C()
    c2.a.x = 10
    print(b1.a.x)
    print(b2.a.x)
    print(c1.a.x)
    print(c2.a.x)

yields:
A.__init__
B.__init__
B.__init__
A.__init__
C.__init__
A.__init__
C.__init__
5
5
1
10

I would have expected 'print(b1.a.x)' to print '1', but it printed '5'. So the argument passed to b1 and b2 is the same. Roughly speaking are these arguments evaluated once at the beginning and then passed to all new initialization?

Tl;dr: Yes, default arguments are evaluated only once at the moment of function definition, not on calls to it.
